# Elegir acción según navegador

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-web

Mi intención es al hacer clic en una imagen que es un hipervínculo a un video, se abra en una pestaña distinta si es en Firefox o que se descargue si es en Internet Explorer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es de usar [condiciones condicionales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comentarios_condicionales).

Si quieres detectar si es `Internet Explorar`:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    // Código para descargar
<![endif]-->
```

y para el **resto de navegadores** que no sea `Internet Explorar`

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
    // Abrir pestaña distinta
<!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: Considerando que es para IE, esta es la mejor respuesta, pero la segunda opción no va a funcionar, por que los otros navegadores lo interpretaran como un comentario, debes cerrar el comentario asi `<!--[if !IE]--> <a target="_blank" href="..."> <!--[endif]-->`. Esto hace que solamente IE lo ignore. Salu2

Comment: @rnd - Tienes razón...gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar estos scripts:

```
var es_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
if(es_firefox) {

}
var es_ie = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1;
if(es_ie) { 

}
```

Esto lo he sacado de [aqui](http://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1634-detectar-el-navegador-con-javascript/)

Comment: He respondido a la segunda parte de la pregunta... Si quieres fusionarla, borro mi respuesta. http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33163

Answer (score 0):

Agregando a lo que dice [Alberto Mier](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33157), dejo cómo poner un enlace para que se abra en una pestaña nueva.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.sitio.com">
    <img src="http://www.sitio.com/imagen.png" >
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```js
var es_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
if(es_firefox){
       alert("El navegador que se está utilizando es Firefox");
}

var es_ie = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 ;
if(es_ie){
       alert("El navegador que se está utilizando es Internet Explorer");
}
```

[Aquí](http://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1634-detectar-el-navegador-con-javascript/) encuentras, para cada navegador la condición indicada